# Closing logic in javascript for a popup/modal

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement two very simple popups/modals with the following functionality -
 1. Clicking a button will open the respective popup.
 2. Clicking anywhere on the screen once popup is active, will close the popup.
 3. Clicking on "X" will close the popup.

I am able to achieve the goals mentioned in point 1 and 2. However, I am unable to implement point 3.

HTML -

```
<button id="myBtn1">Open Modal 1</button>
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in first Modal</p>
  </div>
</div>


<button id="myBtn2">Open Modal 2</button>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in second modal</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS - which is obviously incorrect :

```
var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal1');
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "block";
}

btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}


// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}
```

Please find my code here - https://jsfiddle.net/23bL2w9L/

Note - I cannot change the HTML code in any way. Only Javascript should be modified.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have span `Close` only for first modal. I've modified your code dynamically to close modal window. If you have **10 modal** close button, this will work without any modifications.

Changed

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
```

to

```
var span = document.querySelectorAll(".close"); //this will get all `.close` elements
```

Changed,

```
span.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}
```

to

```
for(var i = 0; i < span.length; i++){
  span[i].onclick = function() {
      //modal1.style.display = "none";
      //console.log(this.closest('.modal'));
      this.closest('.modal').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/23bL2w9L/5/

Demo:

```js
var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal1');
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

var span = document.querySelectorAll(".close");

btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "block";
}

btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}


// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < span.length; i++){
  span[i].onclick = function() {
    //modal1.style.display = "none";
    console.log(this.closest('.modal'));
    this.closest('.modal').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn1">Open Modal 1</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in first Modal</p>
  </div>

</div>




<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn2">Open Modal 2</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in second modal</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Just be careful about not overusing `querySelectorAll` which is way slower than `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.

You can get the close button of each modal like this

```
var span1 = modal1.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
```

And bind the click button like this

```
span1.onclick = function() {
  modal1.style.display = "none";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/YannBertrand/23bL2w9L/1/

Answer (score 0):

It's working for the **modal1**, and to do so for the second modal (**modal2**), add this :

```
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];
span2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}
```

Working fiddle : [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/23bL2w9L/2/)

Answer (score 0):

When I try your fiddle code, the button close of modal1 can work, but not for modal2.
In your JS code, you only create action for modal1, you must create one action for modal2 too...

```
var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal1');
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

btn1.onclick = function() {
   modal1.style.display = "block";
}

btn2.onclick = function() {
   modal2.style.display = "block";
}


// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}

span2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}
```